# Where the Google Analytics code must be placed with Yii Framework 1?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, google-analytics, friendly-url

I have a problem with the Google Analytics data with a website developed with Yii Framework (version 1).

I have developed other websites, without Yii Framework, and the Google Analytics shows the right numbers, but in the website developed with Yii, the numbers are lower.

The Google Analytics track code is placed before , in the views/layouts/main.php file.

On other hand, I am creating the friendly URLs through .htaccess, not using the Yii's URL Management.

For example, I have got the next friendly URL:

http://www.basketme.net/news/andray-blatche-is-attractive-for-memphis-and-

This URL only have 1 visit according to Google Analytics, and it happens with all news in my website.

I know, positively, that these news have had more than 1 visit, because they receive some comments via Twitter.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct that you have to use GA(Google Analytics) in main.php layout file before closing body tag. Your script is before closing head tag. 
For GA it's not depending if you are using SEO friendly or not URL. It's collecting data that code is present. So you have to check if on all your pages GA script is existing.